# Building Qt 4.8.1 from src on MacOS using gcc 4.5

Tags: macos, qt, gcc, makefile

I have a question about building Qt SDK  4.8.1 using gcc on Mac. I need to use gcc 4.5 or higher, so I installed mp-gcc45 package using macports (so tried with mp-gcc47), selected this version of gcc, so

```
gcc -v
```

Says me that gcc version 4.5.4 (MacPorts gcc45 4.5.4_6)

So I downloaded QtSDK src from official site, configure it and there is an error at first step:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fconstant-cfstrings"
```

Maybe its stupid solution, but I remove this flags from configure file, so I get a error after make call:

```
g++: unrecognized option '-Xarch_x86_64'
```

Can you give me an advice, how to build Qt using this version of gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-Apple gcc will never work with Qt of any version. Only Apple gcc recognizes those Apple flavored compiler options.

You are stuck with gcc 4.2 on Mac. There's no way around it.